# Comparing two pieces of information to work out similaririties

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting, logic

I have the following predicament. I have information stored in a database already and I will be adding to it. I have the following fields:

```
Title
Location
Description
```

I want to avoid re-adding the same content into the database. However, what seems to be happening with the current setup is I check to see if they exactly the same but sometimes a single char can be out, and it will accept it as two different values.

Is it possible to build in some sort of "fudge factor", to allow for very minor differences in the two. II am looking more generially for the technique, but if it makes a difference, I am coding in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic "dirty data" problem.  The goal is to have only clean data in your database, and to identify duplicate data.

The technique depends on your data, if it can be cleaned up easily or if it takes some programming logic.  For example, is the last name "van Rossum" the same as "Vanrossum", or is "Håstad" the same as "Hasted"?  Was that last real-time stock price real, or was it a spike that should be discarded?

There may be no simple answer, apart from a list of rules that are applied to each field.  There probably isn't a single "fudge factor" that can fix all your data.

Your best approach should be related to known "good" values for Title, Location and Description.  Maybe your Locations are well-defined and you can easily detect incorrect location -- then you need to decide what the correct location should be.

Common practices include "kicking out" the data that doesn't match the rules so a human can decide, or simply marking it as dirty so a human can apply mental fudge factors when it appears in search results.